# Proper JSON date time syntax for fullcalendar

Tags: json, date, time, fullcalendar

need some help for the proper syntax for display the event times in agenda view.  The events only shows up under all day despite having allDay set to false.

My json.html page looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        eventSources: [
            {
            url: 'json-events.php',     // use the `url` property
            color: 'yellow',            // an option!
            textColor: 'black',         // an option!
            editable: false
            }, 
            // Dont forget coma - but not on the last one
            {
            url: 'other-events.php',    // use the `url` property
            color: 'red',               
            textColor: 'black', 
            editable: 'false',
            allDay: 'false'             
            }
            // any other sources...             
        ]
    }); 
});
```

One of the php pages looks like this:

```
<?php
    echo json_encode(array(
        array(
            'id' => 112,
            'title' => "What is this?",
            'start' => "2011-10-11T13:00:00",
            'end' => "2011-10-12T15:00:00",
            'allDay' => "false"
        ),
    ));
?>
```

How do I get the events to display in the week and day agend view with the proper time (instead of being listed under the "all day" section)?

Thanks,
Extreme Newbie

Answer (score 1):

After tweaking the code, I got it to work by removing the "" around false.  The php page should look like this:

```
'allDay' => false
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the quotation off of "false". "false" is a string, and false is the correct "bool" false.

Also, your json call should have a query such as...

```
$sql = mysql_query("query") or die(mysql_error());
```

Followed by a while statement to retrieve the information...

```
while($arr = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $array_content[] = $arr;
}
```

Then encode...

```
echo json_encode($array_content);
```

This will render whatever data you have in the database.
A simple if statement within the while statement will change the string to a bool like so...

```
if($arr['allDay'] === "true"){
        $arr['allDay'] = true;
    } else {
        $arr['allDay'] = false;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!